# .scss.erb extension syntax highlighting for scss in aptana/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sass, syntax-highlighting, erb

If I have some eRuby in a scss file, I need to make the extension *.scss.erb. However, doing so causes the sytax highlighting for *.erb rather than *.scss. Is there any way to get eclipse to determine the syntax highlighting more intelligently or at least allow manual syntax assignment like in notepad++?

The only workaround I've found so far is to rename the file *.scss, open it, then rename it back to *.erb so it gets processed correctly later on.

Answer (score 0):

There should be.

What you would do is go to Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations and set the default editor for your *.scss.erb extensions, however there's a bug in Eclipse that prevents file associations with more than one period:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168573

The way I get around the issue is by right clicking the source file in Project Explorer and going to Open With > Other... and selecting Sass Source Editor from there.